# Out of order windows pipes

Tags: c#, c++, .net, ipc, named-pipes

Currently working with pipes to communicate between processes, one in C++ and the other a C# .NET application. My .NET application is sending a long user-inputted lua script via pipes to my C++ application. However when sending, my script is all out of order. Chunks of the script are in separate locations. This is strange as I read the whole script with 1 ReadFile call.

My C# side:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!connected)
        return;
    using (var pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "TestPipe", PipeDirection.Out))
    using (var stream = new StreamWriter(pipe)) 
    { 
        pipe.Connect();
        stream.Write(TextBox.Text);
        pipe.Flush();
    }
}
```

I won’t give my whole C++ code of me reading from the pipe but here is me defining the pipe:

```
HANDLE Pipe = CreateNamedPipe("\\\\.\\pipe\\TestPipe",
PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT,
PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
999999,
999999,
NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
NULL);
```

Am I missing something obvious that is causing writes to my pipe to become semi corrupted?

Any help would be appreciated thanks so much!

Comment: I guess you are using "readfile" to read from the pipe....As you specified PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE, if the message to be read is greater than the number of bytes specified (nNumberOfBytesToRead  parameter), you may see disordered content, as the remainder of the message is read separately by subsequent calls.

Comment: @katamarayudu How could I prevent this from happening then?

Comment: Can you try increasing the number nNumberOfBytesToRead ?

Comment: @katamarayudu Also thanks very much for that info, as I misunderstood what PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE was actually doing.

Comment: @katamarayudu Well, I would but the input is dynamic and just setting nNumberOfBytesToRead would cause conflict in the future when longer scripts are sent.

Comment: Ok. Did you try PIPE_READMODE_BYTE?

Comment: @Naidu Thanks! That was my problem! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PAGE_READMODE_BYTE fixed my issue.